# android:process causes my MyApplication's onCreate method to be called twice. How can I prevent the code running twice?

Tags: android

I am aware that if I use `android:process`in the manifest then the class that extends Application will be called twice. Once, for the app and a second time for the new process.

The problem is I have code in MyApplication (extends Application) which should not be called twice. I want to have a separate process but I only want the code in MyApplication#onCreate to ever be ran once per load.

I tried setting a flag in Shared Preferences but it doesn't work, probably because of the different processes issue

Any ideas?

Comment: Shared Preferences seems ok.  Why did it not work?

Comment: Why not write a simple file (like the way standard Linux processes do, a .pid file) and check for its existence before running the code. You may have to take care of the cleanup though

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause**

From [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) documentation:

> Note: This class does not support use across multiple processes.

That explains why your `SharePreferences` does not work.

**Solution 1:** Using [Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS), but it is deprecated in API level 23

> `public static final int MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`
>
> **This constant was deprecated in API level 23.**
>
> MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does not work reliably in some versions of Android,
> and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling
> concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not
> attempt to use it. Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process
> data management approach such as ContentProvider.

**Solution 2:** Using [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider)

**2.1.** Write your own `ContentProvider`

- We just need a way to store a boolean variable that indicates the `onCreate()` method of `MyApplication` is called for the first time or not, using this solution seems inefficient.

**2.2.** Use pre-defined `ContentProvider` from Android

- The app must declare Read/Write external storage permissions and asking runtime permissions as well. By the way, it confuses users when the first time they open the app.

**Solution 3:** We can use the below flow to implement

- Declare a `BroadcastReceiver` that runs in the same process as your app. Because they run on the same process, so they have the same process id.
- The component (activity, service, receiver, provider) that runs on a separate process (private or global), so they will have a different process id.

**Implementation**

**Step 1.** Create a class that extends from `BoardcastReceiver`, named `AppReceiver`.

```
public class AppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Messenger messenger = intent.getParcelableExtra(MyApplication.EXTRA_MESSENGER);

        int processId = intent.getIntExtra(MyApplication.EXTRA_PROCESS_ID, -1);
        boolean isOnCreateCalledFirstTime = processId == Process.myPid();

        Message message = Message.obtain();
        message.arg1 = isOnCreateCalledFirstTime ? 1 : 0;
        try {
            messenger.send(message);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2.** Add that class to *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AppReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" />
```

**Step 3.** Modify your `MyApplication` class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSENGER = "EXTRA_MESSENGER";
    public static final String EXTRA_PROCESS_ID = "EXTRA_PROCESS_ID";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String pkg = getPackageName();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(pkg, pkg + ".AppReceiver"));

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
                boolean isOnCreateCalledFirstTime = msg.arg1 != 0;
                if (isOnCreateCalledFirstTime) {
                    // TODO: First time onCreate() is called
                } else {
                    // TODO: Next time onCreate() is called
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSENGER, messenger);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROCESS_ID, Process.myPid());

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```